# Replacing middle part of the column inside python script by Pandas (.replace is not working)

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I need to replace exact this part of the column for blank: `" [textinside: "`

I am trying these codes:

```py
df['column name'].str.replace(r'\s[textinside:\s', '', regex=True)

df['column name'].str.replace(' [textinside: ', '')

df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(" [textinside: ","")
```

but it gives me error:

```
error: unterminated character set at position 2
```

or the cell in jupiter is work fine, but the dataframe remains not changed.

What is important that before and after `" [textinside: "`, there are something, for example:

`a [textinside: b`

Edit: Thank you all, I have found working solution, it looks like:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(' \[deprecated:', '')
```

the problem with '[' was solved by `\`

Comment: Unterminated character set at position 2 might be because you haven't closed the quotes, just above this text you have `",)` but this should be `",")`, perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: @Rawson I had typo in the code, I corrected it, sorry.  df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(" [textinside: ","") at the end is just  as an empty space and I am trying to put this but somehow it does not work and for code df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(" [textinside: ","")  or df['column name'].str.replace(r'\s[textinside:\s', '', regex=True) it throw an error I mentioned on the question.

Comment: Your second line is working fine, but remember that this does not change anything in place -- it RETURNS the modified column.  You need `df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(...)`.